# Legacy Selenium IDE - how to make an appropriate xpath manually

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have to deal with pretty complex code. I can create on my own xpaths to some extent. That works for me really well. However now I'm stucked. I've got nested iframes, between them is shared very same code with exceptions of values in iframes. So tags as well as an attributes are very same in two iframes. I need to get out the values using an attributes. Regardless which xpath expression I use, the inspector in Chrome browser always shows me at least two very same img tags. I thought that I can use numbers in square brackets on the end of my expression in order to get value from second one image but this does not work.

Only thing which I have on my mind is to create xpath leading from certain iframe up to attribute which I'm interested with. So let's suppose that my code looks like that

```html
<iframe id="iframeID">
<!-- some further code here -->
<div id="divID">
<img src="some/picture">
</div>
<!-- some further code here -->
</iframe>
```

I gave a try to use xpath like one published below but it is inappropriate. Inspector in Chrome browser can not point to my xpath. So I'm stuck here. Please help me.  What's wrong with my xpath construction? My knowledge regarding xpaths is very limited, I'm pretty certain that someone can have some fun when see my xpath "construction" ;) I know that it can not work, it's proven by inspector in Chrome. How to do it as it is meant to be? I'd like to skip over places in my expression where I added html comments.

```
storeAttribute | xpath=(//*[@id="iframeID"]//following:://*[@id="divID"]/img)/@src | someVariable
```

Comment: what programming language are you using? Can you show us more from your code?

Comment: @AlinStelian As described in title - I need xpath expression to legacy Selenium IDE, so under the hood is java script as I suppose. Yes, I can share the code but I have to modify and publish it -  there is real data which should never be shared.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to play with or inside iframes, you need to move inside it. Also, at some point, you might need to move out iframes.

move out iframe

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

move inside iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameId/or frameIndex");
```

get all the iframes to move between them

```
iframes = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('iframe'));
```

you can loop between iframes and do your job.

Comment: I had Selenium IDE on my mind, not Selenium itself. I know that between iframes I should navigate using selectFrame command but honestly, this does nothing. I always get values from first item. That's not my point, I'd like to get value from second one item, square brackets did not work, as well as switching between the iframes. Iframes are nested. I should enter into 2 iframes by issuing 2 commands: selectFrame | index=6 and afterwards selectFrame | index=1 But this does nothing, I still can not get value from 2nd iframe with picture, however I can do it from 1st one without play with iframes

Comment: Tomorrow I will add modified real thing - I mean actual web page with source code.

Comment: I had experience with Katalon Recorder too. KR works with iframes flawlessly, but that's it. Until now using either legacy Selenium IDE or Katalon Recorder I didn't recieved any promised results.